# Trying to generate random equations and check if the answer is correct. (not working)

Tags: javascript, html

My knowledge of Javascript is relatively basic ( started studying recently).
My code is not working and I really need help.

The purposes of the code below are to:

1. generate random equations.
2. check if the answer (the user input) is correct.
3. If the answer is not correct change an image.
4. if the user had 3 mistakes it resets the page.
5. the '**answer**' ID is for the input and the '**Targil**' ID is for the dynamic text (where the equation is written).
6. function start is to show a 'start' button and turn all the components visible.
7. function A is the problem.

Here is my JavaScript and HTML code:

```js
function start() {
  var button = document.getElementById('start');
  button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
  var vid = document.getElementById('timer');
  vid.play();
  var input = document.getElementById('answer');
  input.style.visibility = 'visible';
  var send = document.getElementById('send');
  send.style.visibility = 'visible';
  var heart = document.getElementById('hearts');
  heart.style.visibility = 'visible';
  A()
}
  function A() {
  var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var result = eval(num1 + "+" + num2);
  var answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
  document.getElementById('targil').innerHTML = num1 + " + " + num2 + " =";
  if (answer > 0 ) {
      if (answer == result) {
          alert("true!!!!");
          counter++;
      }
      else {
          count--;
          var heart = document.getElementById("hearts");
          var heartsrc = heart.getAttribute('src');
          heart.setAttribute("src", "IMAGES/hearts" + count + ".png");
          if (heartsrc == 'IMAGES/hearts1.png') {
              heart.setAttribute("src", "IMAGES/hearts0.png");
              alert("Game over! Your score is: " + counter);
              location.reload(0);
          }
      }
  }
  document.getElementById('timer').currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById("answer").value = '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <title>Level: easy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="headLine">Level: easy</h1>
    <p class="targil" id="targil"></p>
    <input type="button" class="sendanswer" id="start" value="Start" onclick="start()" />
    <input type="text" id="answer" class="answer" placeholder="Your answer..." style="visibility:hidden" />
    <input type="button" class="sendanswer" id="send" value="send" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="A()" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Script1.js"></script>
    <video muted class="timer" id="timer">
        <source src="D:\User files\Downloads/timer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <img src="IMAGES/hearts3.png" class="hearts" id="hearts" style="visibility:hidden" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Java != Javascript` , we need html too use tool `<>` for create  a complete snippet and which is the problem?

Comment: Hi Idan, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider clarifying what you meant by "it's not working" - does this mean that your code threw an error in the console? Does it mean that your HTML page's functionality doesn't actually work? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your code

```
...
        if (answer == result) {
            alert("true!!!!");
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            count--;
...
```

**Variable name:**

it's either `count` or `counter`, pick one :).

**declaration:**

Also, `counter` (if you would call it that) is never defined. add the needed `var counter = 0;` global variable in front of your code

**Logical error:**

When function A() is run, you generate 2 random numbers.
But you need the previous numbers to evaluate the answer with.

So, split this function in half.
1 function to generate the question and 1 to validate the answer.
After the answer is validated, recall the question procedure again.

Without changing the code to much:

html:
onclick should call `ValidateAnswer`:

```
input type="button" class="sendanswer" id="send" value="send" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="ValidateAnswer()" />
```

js

```
  var counter = 0;
  var answer = 0;
  function start() {
    var button = document.getElementById('start');
    button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
    var vid = document.getElementById('timer');
    vid.play();
    var input = document.getElementById('answer');
    input.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var send = document.getElementById('send');
    send.style.visibility = 'visible';
    var heart = document.getElementById('hearts');
    heart.style.visibility = 'visible';
    Question();
  }
  function Question() {
    var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    answer = eval(num1 + "+" + num2);
    document.getElementById('targil').innerHTML = num1 + " + " + num2 + " =";
  }
  function ValidateAnswer() {
    var giverAnswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if (giverAnswer > 0 ) {
        if (giverAnswer == answer) {
            alert("true!!!!");
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            counter--;
            var heart = document.getElementById("hearts");
            var heartsrc = heart.getAttribute('src');
            heart.setAttribute("src", "IMAGES/hearts" + counter + ".png");
            if (heartsrc == 'IMAGES/hearts1.png') {
                heart.setAttribute("src", "IMAGES/hearts0.png");
                alert("Game over! Your score is: " + counter);
                location.reload(0);
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('timer').currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("answer").value = '';
    Question();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try to do it. Btw do I need to call the function that validates the answer after the function that generates the question?

Comment: I changed my answer to include a crude sample. 
'Start' visualises the objects and calls the first 'Question'. 'ValidateAnswer' is called from the button and recalls the next 'Question'.